# How to tint BitmapDrawable in selector on button (programmatically)

Tags: android, button, xamarin, selector, tint

I am trying to create a button selector in code - and adding a tint to the pressed state. However nothing I do seems to affect the BitmapDrawable.
Here's my code (using Xamarin.Android):

```
    void SetSelector(Button b, Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable ();
        BitmapDrawable d1 = new BitmapDrawable (bitmap);
        BitmapDrawable d2 = new BitmapDrawable (bitmap);
        d1.SetColorFilter (global::Android.Graphics.Color.Red, PorterDuff.Mode.Multiply);
        states.AddState (new int[] { global::Android.Resource.Attribute.StatePressed }, d1);
        states.AddState (new int[] { }, d2);
        b.SetBackgroundDrawable (states);
    }
```

I have tried different things. Creating a LightningColorFilter and setting that on the BitmapDrawable, or on the Paint object etc. etc. Nothing seems to have any effect at all.
Is there something fundamentally that I am missing?